# timeout for async calles in Hack

Tags: asynchronous, hacklang

I am looking how to achieve what https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#timeouts gives me, but in hack. I just want to timeout my async call in 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the HSL](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/getting-started/the-hack-standard-library) there is an undocumented but long-standing [`Condition`](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/master/hphp/hsl/src/async/Condition.php) class that allows async blocks to signal each other.

<sup>(`Condition` itself wraps the internal [`ConditionWaitHandle`](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/master/hphp/runtime/ext/asio/ext_condition-wait-handle.cpp) async primitive which has been around since the dawn of Hack async.)</sup>

You can implement a timeout by having the work and a timeout block race to signal a `Condition`:

```php
<?hh // strict
use namespace HH\Asio;
class TimeoutException extends \Exception {}
function timeout<T>(Awaitable<T> $work, int $timeout): Awaitable<T> {
  $condition = new HH\Lib\Async\Condition();
  $work_ = async {
    try {
      $res = await $work;
      $condition->succeed($res);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
      $condition->fail($e);
    }
  };
  $timeout_ = async { await Asio\usleep($timeout); $condition->fail(new TimeoutException()); };
  return $condition->waitForNotificationAsync(async { concurrent { await $work_; await $timeout_; } });
}

<<__EntryPoint>>
async function main(): Awaitable<void> {
  $work = Asio\usleep((int)1E12);
  try {
    await timeout($work, (int)1E6);
  }
  catch(TimeoutException $e) { echo "Timed out"; }
}
```

<sup>If you use `Condition`s more widely just be aware that they can't be signalled twice and will raise `HH\InvariantException` to the loser of any races to signal them. Here those exceptions are confined to the async block wrappers in `timeout()`.</sup>

Comment: As a side note, you may have noticed an `HH\Asio\cancel` function in the Hack docs which would also fit the bill, but my attempts with it have failed to actually cancel `usleep` `Awaitable`s at least.

Answer (score 0):

The language does not support it by design.

Unfortunatelly.